# geometry mensuration

Tags: geometry

There are 4 triangles in trapezium when both diagonals are drawn. And area of opposite triangle  are 15 and 20 units and second pair of opposite triangles are equal. What is the area of these equal triangles?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the trapezoid. Call the vertices (going counterclockwise) $A,B,C,D$. Let the "bottom" side be $AB$, and the side parallel to the bottom side $CD$. Let the diagonals mmet at $P$.

Note that $\triangle ABP$ and $\triangle CDP$ are similar. Let the area of $\triangle ABP$ be $20$. Then the sides of $ABP$ are $\sqrt{4/3}$ times the corresponding sides of $\triangle CDP$.

In particular, $\frac{MB}{MD}\sqrt{4/3}$. It follows that the area of $\triangle MBC$ is $\sqrt{4/3}$ times the area of $\triangle MDC$. Thus the area of $\triangle MDC$ is $15\sqrt{4/3}$. This can be simplified to $10\sqrt{3}$.

**Remark:** The areas of each of the two "side" triangles is the *geometric mean* of $15$ and $20$.  This is a general result: if the two similar triangles have areas $p$ and $q$, then the side triangles have area $\sqrt{pq}$.